# Change userData directory Electron Cordova

Tags: cordova, electron, electron-builder

I'm creating multiplatform native app in Ionic and Cordova using Angular.
When app is compiled for windows I'm using Electron (v4) and electron-builder.
I have my electron app installed a few times in different folders and I would like for each installation to use a separate userData directory.
I've tried using `app.setPath('userData', '{INSTALL_DIR}/data')` in preload script and in cordova custom plugin, but those approaches don't work properly cause it is executed after `app.ready` event has been fired.
Placing above code in electron main process in `cdv-electron-main.js` works perfectly but it's a very bad workaround (in addition not recommended in Cordova Electron docs).
I also think that I can't use flag `--user-data-dir`, because I have a custom electron settings file defined in cordova `config.xml`.
Do you have any ideas how to change userData directory before `app.ready` event fired without modifying electron main process?